# Fourier transform of atomic displacements

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals, phonons

In lattice dynamics and the study of phonons, authors always start with a "Fourier transform" of atomic displacements $\mathbf{u}_j$ for each atom $j$ in a unit cell:

$$ \mathbf{u}_j=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\mathbf{q}}\mathbf{X}(j,\mathbf{q})e^{i\cdot\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}(j)}$$

where $N$ is the number of unit cells, $\mathbf{q}$ is a wave vector, $\mathbf{X}(j,\mathbf{q})$ is a displacement of $j$ in normal mode coordinates, and $\mathbf{r}(j)$ is the lattice vector to the unit cell of atom $j$.

No one, however, explains where this expression comes from or why they use it. At first glance, it looks like a typical discrete Fourier transform but it's normalized by $\sqrt{N}$.

1. Why do people normalize by $\sqrt{N}$?
2. How exactly is this a "Fourier transform" of atomic displacements?
3. What does this expression mean, conceptually?
4. What is the meaning of the term $e^{i\cdot\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}(j)}$? Why does it represent the position of the *unit cell* of atom $j$, and not the actual position of atom $j$?

Comment: I think this is not a Fourier transform but rather a Fourier series? I think that might explain almost all four questions?